# Surface integral $\iint_{\Sigma} (x+y)zd\sigma$, with $\Sigma$ the surface of the cube $[0,1]^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A cube is not a smooth surface, so I decided the take its 6 faces as smooth surfaces $\Sigma_i, i=1,\dots,6$.
I'm wondering if I have to calculate all of the integrals to find the result. This seems like a lot of (but not very hard) work. Is there a shorter/faster method?

---

Take for example the face $\Sigma_1$ in the $xz$-plane. A good parameterization would be $\vec{\varphi}(u,v) = (u,0,v), (u,v) \in [0,1]\times[0,1]$. It is clear that $$ \left\|\frac{\partial{\vec{\varphi}}}{\partial u} \times\frac{\partial{\vec{\varphi}}}{\partial v}\right\| = 1,$$ therefore $$ \iint_{\Sigma_1}(x+y)zd\sigma = \int_0^1\int_0^1 uvdudv = \frac14.$$

Do I have to repeat this procedure for all faces?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i am wondering if there is something you can do to convert this to a triple integral over the cube itself, or to convert individual double integrals to line integrals around the face perimeter...

Comment: Each of the $\Sigma_i$ are parallel to one of the coordinate faces, so you know their normal vectors are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ and each surface element reduces to $\mathrm d\sigma=\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$. You can ignore the face with $z=0$. The integrand has some symmetry that you can exploit to only have to worry about 3 simple integrals.